# Полиморфизм

Tags: c++

***Требуются помощь с реализацией трех задач.
Думаю над их реализацией больше недели.
Я догадываюсь, что здесь нужно использовать полиморфизм. Но как - не могу понять.***

**Вот они:**

1. Есть некоторый класс, в котором обязательно есть 1 виртуальная функция, которая не работает с данными класса но что-то выводит на экран.
   Объявление класса есть. Как вызвать эту функцию не используя ее имя?
2. Есть указатель на объект класса, и через него вызывается функция (p-> F ()). Как не меняя класса обеспечить, чтобы при вызове функции F (), вызывалась не она, а новая моя функция?
3. Есть класс в котором объявлено функцию и элемент типа int I. через указатель вызывается функция, которая возвращает элемент. и он выводится на экран.

   ```
   cout << p-> GetI ();
   ```

Как сделать, чтобы при вызове функции `GetI ()` вызывалась не она, а новая моя функция, которая изменит элемент `int I` умножив его на 10 и выведет на экран?

**Добавлено**.
Я уточнил 2 и 3 задания.

- Есть класс в котором объявлено метод и элемент типа `int`. Через указатель на объект класса вызывается метод, который возвращает значение элемента `int`. Как не меняя реализацию класса обеспечить , чтобы при вызове метода через указатель вызывался не он, а моя глобальная функция, которая изменит элемент пита `int` умножив его на 10?

Важно - наследование использовать нельзя; соответственно нельзя создавать новых классов.

- Есть класс в котором объявлено метод и элемент типа `int`. Через указатель на объект класса вызывается метод, который возвращает значение элемента `int`. Как не меняя реализацию класса обеспечить , чтобы при вызове метода через указатель вызывался не он, а моя глобальная функция.

Важно - наследование использовать нельзя; соответственно нельзя создавать новых классов.

Comment: Если это задание, то выложите слово в слово, а не своими словами.

Comment: по первой задаче - я знаю только один способ вызвать функцию, не называя ее имя, при этом, что бы она была виртуальной - это деструктор.

Comment: Ваш вопрос неприятно читать! Хоть бы перечитывали, прежде чем отправлять! Что это:

>> Требуются помощь 

>> объявлено функцию и элемент

Я не говорю про обособление деепричастных оборотов и стилистические ошибки.

Comment: Возможно нужно перегрузить operator->, как  думаете?

Comment: А к первой задаче какое решение подошло?

Comment: А кто его знает, какой ужасный хак ваш преподаватель имел в виду. Может, он хотел запатчить метод прямо в памяти?

Comment: Разве можно перегружать оператор -> для сырых указателей? 
Его можно перегрузить для класса но:

 -  "..Через **указатель на объект класса** вызывается метод.."
 - Даже перегрузив указатель и разместив там вызов глобальной функции, метод всё равно будет вызван.

@Taras Hrytsenko
А вы на лекциях были? Может там подробно объяснялись эти хаки и преподаватель так вычисляет тех кто реально занимался(остальные просто в интернете не найдут ответы)?

Comment: правильным был этот ответ -
# include <iostream.h>

class A {
public:
     virtual void func () {std :: cout << "Hello \ r \ n";}
};

typedef void (* func_type) ();

int main ()
{
     A * a = new A;
     / * a-> func () * / / / НЕ вызывая по имени!
     / / Указатель на таблицу виртуальных функций
     func_type * _vptr_table = * reinterpret_cast <func_type**> (a);
     / / Указатель на первую и единственную функцию в таблице
     func_type f = _vptr_table [0];
     / / Вызывая по указателю!
     f ();
     delete a;
     return 0;
}

только я его немного изменил.

Comment: я был на всех лекциях.
Эти задачи,  что написал, на дополнительные баллы.
основные я уже сдал.
просто хочется узнать как изменить эту замену между функциями не нарушая условий.

Comment: @Taras Hrytsenko: Понятно. Передайте преподавателю, что он профессионально непригоден. Для вас на будущее: никогда не применяйте такую «технику», это опасный код. Если вы напишете такое, любой разумный архитектор тут же выгонит вас с работы.

Answer (score 4):

Задания сформулированы ужасно, мои сочувствия вам.

1) Что означает «не используя ей имя»? Чтобы вызвать функцию, надо указать её имя в той или иной форме. То, работает функция с данными класса или нет, полностью несущественно.

Можно произвести от данного класса производный класс, не переопределять в нём нужную функцию, в написать другую функцию-обёртку.

```
class Given
{
public:
    virtual void func() { cout << "Done" << endl; }
};

class Derived : public Given
{
public:
    void wrapper() { func(); }        
}

// вызов без использования имени
Derived d;
d.wrapper();
```

Можно тупо заменить вызов макросом:

```
#define WRAP() func()
Given g;
g.WRAP();
```

По существу отличающихся корректных способов не вижу.

2) Если функция виртуальная, породите класс от данного и перекройте функцию.

```
class Given
{
public:
    virtual string func() { return "Given"; }
};

class Derived : public Given
{
public:
    virtual string func() { return "Overridden"; }
}

Given* p = new Derived;
cout << p->func();
```

Если нет, невозможно. Хотя подход с макросом пройдёт, если есть хоть какая-то виртуальная функция.

3) То же самое. Если функция `GetI` виртуальная, породите класс от данного и перекройте функцию. Если нет, корректно сделать невозможно.

Comment: относительно первого примера:
показывал его (реализовал так же как и вы) преподавателю так он сказал, что не выполнены условия задачи, а именно - виртуальная функция должна встречаться только один раз - в объявлении класса. А мы  в производном классе используем ее имя , что не является верным согласно условию задачи.

я вот думаю - может через указатель на функцию?

Comment: Тогда уточните условие задания. Класс _уже есть_ или вы должны его сами реализовать? Условие о том, что функция не работает с данными класса, намекает, что преподаватель хочет от вас какой-то грязный трюк, несовместимый со стандартом языка (типа `reinterpret_cast` в класс с таким же лэйаутом памяти).

Answer (score 4):

1) Получите указатель на таблицу виртуальных функций. Вызовите функцию прямо по адресу.

Пример кода:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    virtual void func() { std::cout << "Hello\r\n"; }
};

typedef void (*func_type)();

int main()
{
    A* a = new A;
    /*a->func();*/ // не вызываем по имени! 
    // указатель на таблицу виртуальных функций
    func_type* _vptr_table = *reinterpret_cast<func_type**>( a );       
    // указатель на первую и единственную функцию в таблице
    func_type f = _vptr_table[0]; 
    // вызываем по указателю!
    f();
    delete a;
    return 0;
}
```

Чтобы понять, что такое таблица виртуальных функций: [Таблица виртуальных функций на Wikipedia](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2#.D0.92.D1.8B.D0.B7.D0.BE.D0.B2)

По 2) и 3) Согласен с [@VladD](/users/10105/vladd). Унаследоваться и перекрыть виртуальную функцию.

Comment: Нууууу... Это же хак, разве нет? Реализация виртуальных функций через таблицу виртуальных функций не гарантирована стандартом. Поэтому, например, оптимизатор имеет право выкинуть ТВМ, даже если она и была в отладочном режиме.

Я думаю, корректного переносимого решения по пункту 1 нету.

Comment: PS: интересно, что имел в виду преподаватель?

Comment: Думаю, как раз vptr, раз нельзя больше нигде использовать имя метода.

Comment: Эх, вы правы. В любом случае, преподаватель заставляет писать код с багами и крешами by design, пичалька.

Comment: А можно ли определить в каком порядке туда(в таблицу) попадают указатели на методы и члены?

Например я попробовал менять местами функцию и переменную int в объявлении.  В _vptr_table[0]  всё равно на первом идет функция func(), а в _vptr_table[1] уже int. Но порядок для переменных сохраняется, то есть _vptr_table[2] будет int2, _vptr_table[3] будет int3 и.т.д

Comment: @manking: Это надо смотреть в документации каждого конкретного компилятора. Никакого стандарта нет.

Answer (score 2):

Это не ответ.

Из ответа atwice:

Используя reinterpret_cast<тип*> мы получаем все указатели на переменные или виртуальные методы данного типа, которые есть в структуре. Они идут по порядку их объявления.

Важный отрывок из условия задачи:

> `Есть некоторый класс, в котором обязательно есть 1
> виртуальная функция, которая не
> работает с данными класса но что-то
> выводит на экран`

Если это "литературно" разобрать, то

```
class A
{
public:
virtual void func() { std::cout << "Hello\r\n"; } // одна обязательная виртуальная функция
void func2(); // не обязательная не виртуальная функция
virtual void func3() { std::cout << "Hello3\r\n"; } // не обязательная вторая виртуальная функция

int D; // данные класса с которыми не работает func(). Значит они есть.
};
```

Правильный ответ atwice.
Но если поменять местами func3 и func то ответ atwice не правильный.
Так как будет вызвана func3().

Но если мы знаем в какой последовательности будут расположены виртуальные функции в объявлении класса, то ответ atwice всё же будет правильным, достаточно будет изменить _vptr_table[0] на _vptr_table[n] в зависимости от порядка расположения виртуальных  функций с одинаковым прототипом, при условии поддержки данного механизма в конкретной версии среды разработки и соблюдении необходимых настроек компиляции.

**Вывод:**

Зная прототип этой обязательной виртуальной функции и порядок расположения в структуре виртуальных функций с таким же прототипом, мы можем вызвать эту функцию не зная её имени, используя таблицу виртуальных функций.

Однако если условие задачи автора на самом деле иное, и предполагается что нельзя делать вызов функции по имени которое объявлено в классе, то правильными будут ответы VladD и 
perfect.

Comment: Эээ... Ну почему снова таблица виртуальных методов?

Comment: Страуструп: издание 2010. стр.77

"Таблицы виртуальных функций позволяют корректно использовать объекты даже в тех случаях, когда на момент вызова функции неизвестны ни размеры объекта, ни местоположение его данных. Единственное что нужно знать вызывающей стороне - это расположение таблицы vtbl класса(с помощью  reinterpret_cast мы вытащили vtbl с соответствующим прототипом) и индексы в этой таблице для вызова виртуальных функций(это определяется на глазок)."

Comment: Мне кажется что преподаватель почитал про это и решил применить. То есть раз в его учебной программе(книге) про это есть, то это следует и студентам задавать. А на стандарты ему всё равно, для него стандарт это его учебный материал. И какого года этот материал его не волнует.

Comment: Я бы не употреблял слово «объяснялись» насчёт хаков типа прямого вызова через таблицу виртуальных методов. Грамотный преподаватель должен был бы потратить занятие, чтобы объяснить, почему такого в принципе нельзя делать.

Answer (score 1):

По поводу первого пункта в вопросе. Проанализируйте это:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class C{
public:
    virtual void draw(){    // настоящее имя
         cout << "hello" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    C * theClass = new C;
    void (C::*blabla)();

    blabla = &C::draw;

    (theClass->*blabla)(); // уже ненастоящее имя

    delete theClass;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: draw должно присутствовать один раз. У вас два раза.

Там где blabla = &C::draw;

Comment: Ну, если заниматься подсчётами токенов, то:

    #define FUNC draw
    virtual void FUNC(){    // настоящее имя
         cout << "hello" << endl;
    }
    blabla = &C::FUNC;

Comment: @VladD 
В вашем ответе про макросы говорилось, и насколько понял из последующих комментариев, это совсем не то.

Насколько я понял условие такое:

 C * theClass = new C;

Мы создали экземпляр класса С, theClass. 
Мы знаем, что там есть только 1 функция. Мы знаем её прототип. Нам надо вызвать её.

Правильно?

Comment: @manking: Если условие такое, как вы говорите, то да, с макросами не катит. Но если мы не знаем имени, то мы не угадаем и её позицию в таблице виртуальных методов.

Comment: Вы сейчас бесконечный цикл из комментариев создадите. Человек поставил задачу такую:

Есть некоторый класс, в котором обязательно есть 1 виртуальная функция, которая не работает с данными класса но что-то выводит на экран. Объявление класса есть. Как вызвать эту функцию не используя ее имя?

@manking , где вы в вопросе увидели - Мы знаем её прототип, но не знаем имени и про никакие - draw должно присутствовать один раз там не написано.

я считаю если все условия человека задавшего вопрос удовлетворены то вопрос решен правильно.

Comment: Разве в этом комментарии не об этом?

"а именно - виртуальная функция должна встречаться только один раз - в объявлении класса. А мы в производном классе используем ее имя , что не является верным согласно условию задачи."

Comment: @manking ладно вы пишите: а именно - виртуальная функция должна встречаться только один раз - в объявлении класса

посмотрите мой код: есть класс С в нем только одна виртуальная функция (условие соблюдено)

________________________________
вы пишите: А мы в производном классе используем ее имя.

в вопросе автора про производные классы ничего нет (значит вы придумали это сами)